# Detect multi-digit numbers seperated by spaces in a string

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that returns the largest and smallest number in a string. However, not all numbers in the string are 1 digit numbers - some are 2 or 3 digits long.

Examples:

```
high_and_low("1 2 3 4 5")      # return "5 1"
high_and_low("1 2 -3 4 5")     # return "5 -3"
high_and_low("12 9 314 4 -57") # return "314 -57"
```

*This exercice originates from [codewars.com](https://www.codewars.com/)*

Comment: @PranavHosangadi My bad. Though, I'd like to point out that I made several attempts, and listing what I've tried would just make me look somewhat stupid (considering that none of my methods worked). In the future, should I include my own attempts anyway, no matter how bizarre or unfunctional they are?  I'll also have a look at the checklist and the other things you suggested. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Yes, you should include your best attempt and explain what went wrong with it. Being able to identify and describe the problem is an important first step to fixing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really easy to do with a list comprehension and int conversion

```
def high_and_low(nums)
    nums = [int(n) for n in nums.split()]
    return max(nums), min(nums)
```

Comment: Let's not reward questions that demonstrate no effort on OP's part with an answer. Giving the code for such questions only encourages more [off-topic](/help/on-topic) posts. "Gimme teh code" is not on-topic here.

Comment: Ok, understood.

Answer (score 0):

You can use str.split!

```
numbers = "1 2 3 4 5 38 -44"
numbers_strings = numbers.split() # turns into ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '38', '-44']
numbers = list(map(int, numbers_strings)) # turns into [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 38, -44]
print(max(numbers), min(numbers))
```

If you want to use something else as the seperator, you can pass it as an argument to split() - eg `"1|2|3".split('|') == ['1', '2', '3']`

Comment: Let's not reward questions that demonstrate no effort on OP's part with an answer. Giving the code for such questions only encourages more [off-topic](/help/on-topic) posts. "Gimme teh code" is not on-topic here.